# Tuning logstash performance

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I use logstash to connect between elasticsearch and ntopng(a flow collector).
but there are many drop flows, so I think the bottle neck is on logstash because my RAM is 20G and CPU 8 cores.
But I am not sure which parameter could I edit to tune the logstash in the logstash.yml

thank you in advance!

Comment: Since you're giving no information, all I can give you is this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/performance-tuning.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like one step of working out a solution to your problem is to supply decent Logstash monitoring. One good way to achieve this is by installing X-Pack which provides Logstash monitoring in the X-Pack monitoring ui in Kibana.

Please refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/logstash-monitoring-ui.html for more information about the Logstash monitoring ui and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/installing-xpack-log.html for information on how to install and configure X-Pack for Logstash.

Apart from Logstash monitoring, you should of course also monitor the used resources on the systems you are running Logstash on. There are several ways to do this, for example with active monitoring solutions, such as Nagios, our passive monitoring solutions such as Elasticsearch with Metricbeat.

Once you know what the bottleneck is, you can go through https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/performance-troubleshooting.html and tune Logstash settings or if necessary add more Logstash instances for distributing load.